# How to remove .on() function in pty.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pty

I'm using [pty.js](https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/) in node, and I go:

```
if (!global.terminal)
global.terminal = pty.spawn('ssh', [sshuser + sshhost, '-p', sshport, '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=' + sshauth], {
            name: 'xterm-256color',
            cols: 80,
            rows: 28
        });

 var term1 = global.terminal;

 term1.on('data', function(data) { socket.emit('output1', data); console.log('on data: ' + data); });
```

Now, I don't ever term1.end() because I don't want the terminal session to close, even when the user closes the browser. So I keep global.terminal. However, I noticed whenever a new socket connects (Ie I refresh the browser) then the .on method gets called twice, thrice, or however many times I refreshed. because it keeps the .on of the last connection.

**Basically a way to clear the .on event** and start a brand new one.

So what I'm looking for is a way to clear the .on event before creating a new one. I'm not sure if this is a javascript/node thing or a pty.js thing:

But something like:

```
 term1.on('data', null); // <-- doesn't work, clear any existing '.on' functions
 term1.on('data', function(data) { socket.emit('output1', data); console.log('on data: ' + data); });
```

Comment: `.on('end'......)`?

Comment: IDK, it looks like a descent question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing an EventEmitter's listeners can be done with the method [`removeAllListeners(eventName)`](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removealllisteners_eventname). Which in your case would look like this:

```
term1.removeAllListeners('data');
```